react: использование хука из функции, вызываемой в компоненте, а не из самого компонента
Необходимо в React из функции (не компоненте, но функция вызывается из компонента) выполнить навигацию
Создал хук:
// хук для выполнения навигации
export const useCustomNavigate = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    return navigate;
  };

И использую внутри функции:
    // обработать 401 ошибка: не авторизованный запрос
    if (errMessage === 'Unauthorized') {
        // выйти из системы
        logout()

        // перейти на страницу авторизации
        const navigate = useCustomNavigate();

        navigate('/auth/login');
    }

и получаю ошибку:

React Hook "useCustomNavigate" is called in function "queryCustom"
that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook
function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter.
React Hook names must start with the word "use"
react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Подскажите как с этим бороться?
не хочется выполнять этот код в самом компоненте, в компоненте работать с useNavigate()
хочется чтоб такая вещь (которая много где используется) выполнялась централизованно (код лежал бы в утилитах как отдельная функция) и желательно ничего бы не требовал от компонента на вход (если это возможно)
Подскажите как решить данную проблему?
P.S.
как временное решение (не знаю насколько оно правильное) я в main.tsx (по сути в главном компоненте) использовал
const navigate = useNavigate();

а navigate положил в синглтон и использую navigate по всему проекту

но функция вызывается из компонента Чего бы тогда ее не сделать хуком?

ksa, поясни PLZ, не совсем понял

Ты вызываешь некую функцию из компонента... В ней пытаешься вызвать хук и получаешь ошибку. Так ты сделай ту функцию так же хуком, а в хуках можно вызывать другие хуки.

Или ты про пользовательские хуки не слышал? https://ru.legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

Или та функция вызывается не совсем "из компонента"?

в общем то да, функция, которая использует навигацию лишь часть общего функционала и заворачивать ее в хук - ничего не даст мне в качестве упрощения или облегчения кода, потому что большие функции из которых вызывается эта малая в хуки не завернешь

Можешь сделать некий схематичный пример? Может на нем можно будет что-то предложить как решение проблемы? Ведь без разницы какой хук делать для примера... Главное понять где ты его собрался "втыкнуть" и в какую именно функцию...


Необходимо в React из функции (не компоненте, но функция вызывается из компонента) выполнить навигацию

Вот смотри... В примере есть хук и функция. Есть вариант привязки всего этого в компоненте. Есть и вызов функции. Т.е. вроде как все твое имеется.
Если в поле будет значение Unauthorized будет выполнен "переход" по твоему УРЛ.


// хук для выполнения навигации
const useCustomNavigate = () => {
  //const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [navigate, setNavigate] = React.useState('');
  return [navigate, setNavigate]
};

//
function test(navigate) {
  return function(errMessage) {
    // обработать 401 ошибка: не авторизованный запрос
    if (errMessage === 'Unauthorized') {
      // выйти из системы
      //logout()
      // перейти на страницу авторизации
      //const navigate = useCustomNavigate();
      navigate('/auth/login');
    }
  }
}
//
function App() {
  const [val, setVal] = React.useState('')
  const [navigate, setNavigate] = useCustomNavigate()
  const fnc = test(setNavigate)
  const act = e => {
    const v = e.target.value
    fnc(v)
    setVal(v)
  }
  return <section>
    <input type='text' onChange={act} value={val} />
    <p>{navigate}</p>
  </section>
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(<App />);
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="like_button_container"></div>



